# Rails 3 - Ajax POSTS from a link click

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a link that will perform an ajax post request... the rails 3 way.

I set up my link

```
<%= link_to "my link", things_path(:thing_type => 1, :user_id => person.id), :remote => true, :method => "post", :format => :js %>
```

The post works and creates the record but it complains about missing csrf token (which is in my meta tags).

How can I get rails.js to send the csrf token when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember there was a rails.js script that had this bug in Rails 3.

You should probably update your jquery-rails and regenerate rails.js or just replace rails.js with this one https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js